# how to set programmatically field components in grid edit mode

Tags: javascript, extjs4

I want to edit a grid with comboxbox and fields. 
While editing the selected row, On select event of combobox i want to set some value from database to the field in grid.
I don't know how to set any value in a field control while row is in edit mode. 
some one suggested "with an EditorGridPanel you're supposed to assign editing to controls and not directly database" me but i dont know how to.

here is my code

```
var triprate_idEditor = {
xtype         : 'combobox'
, typeAhead     : true 
, triggerAction : 'all'
, displayField  : 'name'
, valueField    : 'id'
, store         : 'TriprateAllStore'
, queryMode     : 'local'
, emptyText     : 'Select a name...'
, listeners: 
  {
   select: function(combo, rec) {
        console.log(' here');
//        var triprateall = Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('TriprateAllStore');
//        triprateall.filter(id:combo.value);

        var g = Ext.getCmp('Tripgrid-Id');
        //return default value 0
        console.log(g.getSelectionModel().selected.items[0].data.triprate); 

    //get triprate from database, excluded here 
    //set triprate to 400 but not in editor
    g.getSelectionModel().selected.items[0].data.triprate = 400;

    //return value 400
        console.log(g.getSelectionModel().selected.items[0].data.triprate); 
    }
}

var rowEditing = Ext.create('Ext.grid.plugin.RowEditing', {
    clicksToEdit: 2,
    id: 'TripEditingGrid',
    errorSummary: false
});

Ext.define('Fleet.view.grids.TripGrid',
{
    extend      : 'Ext.grid.Panel',
    alias       : 'widget.Tripgrid',  //xtype
    id          : 'Tripgrid-Id',  //Unique Id
    store       : 'TripStore',
    selType     : 'rowmodel',
    plugins: [rowEditing],
    columns :
            [
          {
              header    : 'id'
            , dataIndex : 'id'
            , width     : 80
            , field     : { xtype     : 'numberfield' } 
          },
          {
              header    : 'triprate id'
            , dataIndex : 'triprate_id'
            , width     : 100
            , filter    : true
            , editor    : triprate_idEditor
            , renderer  : function(value, metaData, record, rowIndex, colIndex, store, view){
                    return record.data.triprate_name7; //desc column for display in gird
                  }
          },
          {
              header    : 'triprate'
            , dataIndex : 'triprate'
            , width     : 80
            , field     : { xtype     : 'numberfield' } 
          },
          {
              header    : 'status'
            , dataIndex : 'status'
            , width     : 70
            , renderer  : formatBoolean
            , editor    : checkboxEditor 
          }
            ]
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should use `editor` property when defining grid columns and put your code defining combobox editor there.

Comment: Thanks sha for quick replay. i have defined grid columns with editor property <b>, editor    : triprate_idEditor</b> that is defined in the code header. var triprate_idEditor = { .....}